# Better way to handle page that links to hundreds of binaries?

Tags: tridion

I've struggled with a better solution for the following setup. I'm not actively working on this, but know some that might appreciate other ways of handling this.

Setup:

- Tridion-managed page has a single "linked list" component Linked list
- Single component has component links to other components in Tridion
- Linked-to components often link to multimedia component (mm)
- An XSLT component template (XSLT CT) renders XML with above content and with links to PDF

  - XSL document() function used to grab embedded (linked-to) content, all content converted to XML nodes and attributes
  - TCMScriptAssistant namespace with publishBinary() publishes related PDF and other media
- Page template just outputs the result of the CT

Business requirements:

1. improved publishing (last I worked on this, some of these files created a 2GB publishing transaction because of the PDFs)
2. published XML content file must reference the associated PDFs; hyperlinks work but identifiers might not help because of...
3. no Tridion content delivery APIs, mainly for independence from the storage database but also to avoid Tridion-specific code on the presentation server (loosely coupled setup and less training for developers)

The biggest issue is the huge transport package during publishing. The second problem is publishing any of the linked-to PDFs will cause the page to republish.

**How could this setup be improved or re-engineered**, preferably without too many changes to the existing templates, though modular templating could be considered.

Dynamic component presentations could possibly work, but would need to be published to the file system and not use dynamic linking or broker objects (e.g. no criteria filters, binary metadata, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed 2 questions. I will handle them in reverse order.

To prevent the page from being republished when you publish a binary, you can use the event system in older versions of Tridion (pre-2011) to turn off link resolving, or with  newer versions you can use a custom resolver to prevent this. There is an article by Nuno which explains this(http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/10/tridion-publisher-and-custom-resolvers.html)

Your second one is a bit tougher, in no small part because of your criteria for not using the SDL Tridion CD APIs. I would have suggested publishing the binaries separately (this would keep the file size down of your transaction package), and using Binary Linking to resolve the paths at request time.

Given this is not an option, I think the only was I  would approach it would be to still use dynamic component presentations, and then use predictable unique file names for the PDfs (i.e. use something like 317-12345.pdf based on the URI), and use one directory for all the binaries. That way you could enter the paths to the binary using your XSLT template, as you know where the binaries will be located later. You could then use a custom resolver to publish the binaries when you publish the main list component or page.

Hope that helps

Chris

Comment: I saw Nuno's post earlier, but it makes much more sense in the context of your answer. I believe the existing setup already used a regular expression to change component titles; I think the same idea could make those predictably unique paths. This definitely helps!